# Regex substitution over a large file

Tags: regex, perl

Given a large file (potentially 1.5GB) with some very long lines, I need to run substitutions. I thought of running a sliding window where I `read` 4096 bytes off the file, append them to the previous chunk and substitute on that, but of course that doesn't work so well for substitutions where the substitution might be across the fold.

Another thought came to mind that I could start with my first two chunks and `s///` on that. if there are no substitutions made I write chunk1 to disk and grab chunk3. Then I `s///` on chunk2 and chunk3. If there are substitions I grab chunk4 and append it. Then I keep appending until there's no substitions. At that point I write everything but the latest chunk to disk. Like this:

```
read( $data, $previous_chunk, 4096 );
while( read( $data, $this_chunk, 4096 ) > 0 ){
    my $chunk = $previous_chunk . $this_chunk;
    if( 0 == $chunk =~ s/foo/bar/g ){
        # There was nothing to substitute, so we'll append all 
        # the old stuff to our file and just keep the latest chunk.
        print OUTPUT $previous_chunk;
        $previous_chunk = $this_chunk;
    }
    else {
        # There was a substitution, so we want to keep building 
        # in case it crossed the fold
        $previous_chunk .= $this_chunk;
    }
}
```

Does that sound sane? The only problem I can see is that if the substitution causes a new match in the running `$previous_chunk`. So we probably need to clear `$previous_chunk` up to the latest substitution somehow and only keep the clean content that follows it. (Eg, if we had `s/foo/foobar/` we'd turn 'foo' into 'foobar' then into 'foobarbar' then into 'foobarbarbar'. Is there a way to avoid that?

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: How much memory have you got? Can you simply read the whole file into memory, do the substitution, and write it out again? It's a big hammer, but it might work for your purposes.

Comment: Depends on the nature of the replacements.  As Greg points out, it might be possible to just load the entire file into memory.  However, a lot of the time people are just doing inner-line replacements, so simple line-by-line processing might work depending on the type of translations you're doing.  In the end, need more data to be able to advise better.

Comment: how long is very long?  are all your substitutions suitable to work on a single line?

Comment: What kind of substitutions will you have to perform? Is there no inherent structure in the file which you could use? E.g. if a substitution will never span multiple lines, then reading the file line by line is the most robust and preferable solution, even when the line is multiple MB heavy.

Comment: @Miller, yeah, line by line will probably work. It's sanitising an SQL dump (removing sensitive information) and running the substitution per-line will work fine. I was cheating and just pulling the entire dump into memory. Want to make your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You ask if there is a better way to do it. "Better" is subjective, but this is what I would do if I were faced with the same problem.

One option is not to use Perl at all but to perform your search-and-replace in a text editor that supports gigantic files.

On Windows, one editor that does so is EditPad Pro, which supports huge files. Not my product, so this is not an ad. I use EPP because it is regex-centric (same author as RegexBuddy).

Quoting from [the brochure](http://www.editpadpro.com/manual/epponly.html): `Open and edit files of absolutely any size, including files larger than 4 GB, even on a 32-bit system with a modest amount of RAM.`

This allows you to offload the whole large file issue.

Other features that may or may not be relevant: you can save your regular expressions, chain them with macros, and invoke tools (such as your own Perl scripts) to manipulate the currently open file (though in that case you are once again at the mercy of the outside tool's memory management).

Comment: No, I have plenty of easy options for hand editing it. This is a SQL dump sanitisation script that removes sensitive data.  I think I'll go with one of the solutions in comments and parse it line by line.